# Can deep belief networks be applied to sparse feature vectors/classification problems?

Tags: classification, references, deep-learning, deep-belief-networks

I am trying to beat the performance of an SVM classifier in a text classification task. 
Input is a bag of words model of sentences with 1 representing presence and 0 representing absence. Output is 1 of 4 possible labels. Are DBNs directly applicable to this class of problems? I get an error of 0.38 on the test set and I could not make it any better.
Please refer me to papers/posts where I can find similar problems/applications.

Answer (score 2):

Although you could in principle directly apply a DBN to your data to learn new feature representations, a more promising approach in my view would be to look for models tailored more closely to your problem. Hugo Larochelle, for example, has used and extended RBMs to model both documents and classification problems. Maybe you can find something useful on his website:

http://www.dmi.usherb.ca/~larocheh/projects_classrbm.html

Comment: Thank you for the information. It is helpful . Also i found matrbm at http://code.google.com/p/matrbm/ implements rbmfit that could directly be used for classification problems. Please comment if you know some libraries that do classification with rbm or dbn.

Comment: Hugo Larochelle also has code online. I couldn't tell if it also implements RBMs/DBNs, but this might be of interest to you anyway: http://www.dmi.usherb.ca/~larocheh/mlpython/learners_sparse.html#module-learners.sparse.classification

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Lucas' answer, this paper might be interesting for you:

[Semantic Hashing](http://www.utstat.toronto.edu/~rsalakhu/papers/semantic_final.pdf). A DBN is used to create a bit code for each document based on a bag of words representation. This can serve as features for a subsequent classifier or similarty search.

Comment: +1.  The same authors have [a more recent paper](http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips22/NIPS2009_0817.pdf) on representing bags of words as well.